# Magento 2 PHP intl etension error

Tags: magento2

I am trying to install Magento 2 on Wamp but there is php intl extension error i have enabled the extension and copied all dll files in appache too but magento is still showing error any solution for this 
thanks

Comment: restart apache, or shutdown all wamp services and start again

Comment: No still same error is there any other solution ? please help

Comment: could you upload the error screen which is showing ?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if any issue.

Comment: Did you check it?

Comment: Yes not resolving please help

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and execute this below commands :

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
- sudo service apache2 restart

In windows :

First of all stop the `xampp/wamp` and then kindly remove the starting semicolon ( ; ) from your **xampp/php/php.ini** the following code.

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

And then restart your `xampp/wamp`.

Comment: I am using windows the command is not running

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Please check my comment and guide me how do i solve this . thanks

Comment: Did you first stop service and test start apache?

Comment: YES  i did .....

Comment: Can you please post your php.ini full path here?

Comment: C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.4\php.ini

Comment: copy all 6 files icudt57.dll,icuin57.dll,icuio57.dll,icule57.dll,iculx57.dll,icuuc57.dll From php folder to apache\bin Now Restart you apache service

Comment: Is it working or not?

Comment: no it's not working.

Comment: please refer this link : https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Missing-PHP-extension-intl/td-p/22260

Comment: i have visited that the solutions are not working either